# Repeat audio file, and stop when the task changed

Tags: java, android, delay, repeat

I want to repeat to play audio file which says "Searching" every 1 minute. How can i implement it, to stop this file, when the `CASE_STATUS_SEARCHING` will change to other? I used `TIMER` and `SOUNDPOOL` :

```
public class Player { 
private static SoundPool soundPool;
private static int searching;
final Timer timer = new Timer();


public void searching () {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                       @Override
                       public void run() {
                           soundPool.play(searching, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
                       }
                   }, 60000);
}
```

//and I start thread here :

```
public class Locator BroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
final String action = intent.getAction();

switch (newStatus) {
    case STATUS_SEARCHING:
                        stateStr = getString(R.string.Scanning);
                        tvStatus.setText(R.string.Scanning);
                        Player.searching();
                        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own with little help from stackoverflow.

```
public void playStillSearching() {

    if (handler == null) {
            handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    soundPool.play(stillSearching, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1.0f);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                }
            }, 3000);
    }
}

public void stopSpeak() {

    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

than i implement those to my events.